junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Test is stuck, see ANR stack trace for more info. You may need to create /data/anr first
I'm running Test cases but facing the below error.

junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Test is stuck, see ANR stack
trace for more info. You may need to create /data/anr first

The error occurred in the below code :
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

                initMediaPlayer(mMediaPlayer2);
                mOnCompletionCalled.reset();
                mOnInfoCalled.reset();
                mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(mp -> {
                    assertEquals(mMediaPlayer, mp);
                    mOnCompletionCalled.signal();
                });
                mMediaPlayer2.setOnInfoListener((mp, what, extra) -> {
                    assertEquals(mMediaPlayer2, mp);
                    if (what == MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_STARTED_AS_NEXT) {
                        mOnInfoCalled.signal();
                    }
                    return false;
                });

                mMediaPlayer.setNextMediaPlayer(mMediaPlayer2);
                mMediaPlayer.start();
                assertTrue(mMediaPlayer.isPlaying());
                assertFalse(mOnCompletionCalled.isSignalled());
                assertFalse(mMediaPlayer2.isPlaying());
                assertFalse(mOnInfoCalled.isSignalled());
                while(mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                    Thread.sleep(SLEEP_TIME);
                }
                // wait a little longer in case the callbacks haven't quite made it through yet
                Thread.sleep(100);
                assertTrue(mMediaPlayer2.isPlaying());
                assertTrue(mOnCompletionCalled.isSignalled());
                assertTrue(mOnInfoCalled.isSignalled());

                // At this point the 1st player is done, and the 2nd one is playing.
                // Now swap them, and go through the loop again.
                MediaPlayer tmp = mMediaPlayer;
                mMediaPlayer = mMediaPlayer2;
                mMediaPlayer2 = tmp;
            }

Don't know how to fix this one. please help.
I have taken logs:
03-27 16:21:44.615 1010150  3728  3810 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-2
03-27 16:21:44.615 1010150  3728  3810 E AndroidRuntime: Process: android.media.player.cts, PID: 3728
03-27 16:21:44.615 1010150  3728  3810 E AndroidRuntime: junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Test is stuck, see ANR stack trace for more info. You may need to create /data/anr first
03-27 16:21:44.615 1010150  3728  3810 E AndroidRuntime:    at junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:50)
03-27 16:21:44.615 1010150  3728  3810 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.media.player.cts.MediaPlayerTest.lambda$testSetNextMediaPlayer$5(MediaPlayerTest.java:785)
03-27 16:21:44.615 1010150  3728  3810 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.media.player.cts.MediaPlayerTest$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:2)
03-27 16:21:44.615 1010150  3728  3810 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
03-27 16:21:44.616 1010150  3728  3810 D MonitoringInstr: Handling an uncaught exception thrown on the thread Thread-2.
03-27 16:21:44.616 1010150  3728  3810 D MonitoringInstr: junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Test is stuck, see ANR stack trace for more info. You may need to create /data/anr first
03-27 16:21:44.616 1010150  3728  3810 D MonitoringInstr:   at junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:50)
03-27 16:21:44.616 1010150  3728  3810 D MonitoringInstr:   at android.media.player.cts.MediaPlayerTest.lambda$testSetNextMediaPlayer$5(MediaPlayerTest.java:785)
03-27 16:21:44.616 1010150  3728  3810 D MonitoringInstr:   at android.media.player.cts.MediaPlayerTest$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:2)
03-27 16:21:44.616 1010150  3728  3810 D MonitoringInstr:   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
03-27 16:21:44.616 1010150  3728  3810 W AndroidJUnitRunner: An unhandled exception was thrown by the app.

